# Repeat a Command invoked from Menu

Tags: vim, menu, command, repeat

I created many menu commands in VIM.

`.`  repeats the last command in normal mode.
`@:` repeats the last command from commandline

Is there a way to repeat the last command invoked from vim's **menu**?

**Update:**

example menu command:

```
an 98.80.00 &MyMenu.Test\ :call <SID>Test("%")<CR>
```

If I use this Menu Command created by myself, how can I repeat it again (repeat last used menu command)?
In above case it would be `:call <SID>Test("%")<CR>`
I can't find these commands in command line history.
`@:` and `:<UP>` doesn't work

Does anyone know where Vim saves function calls/menu commands actions?

**Update2**

Kent proposed to build a function around the above command:

```
an 98.80.00 &MyMenu.Test\ :call SubExe('call <SID>Test("%")')<CR>

 function! SubExe(argument)
  let g:lastcommand = a:argument
  exe g:lastcommand
 endfun
```

It seems to work, the disadvantage is that I have to change all current commands ;)

Comment: I always thought it would be great if I can repeat a group of commands, rather than just the last command. The answer to this is obviously using macros (qa<set of commands>q then @a to repeat), but I was looking for something easier and faster. Can't you use macros?

Comment: Yes, but if I'm not mistaken you have to create a macro for every menu command that you need to repeat.

Comment: Yes, that's write, but I suppose you wouldn't need that frequently, yeah? Otherwise, just map a key to the menu command then keep pressing that key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no built-in support, you have to build one on your own, if it is so important to you. Basic idea is:

You create a function, like `ExecMenuCmd(cmd)` the argument is the command, like `wq`, in the function, you save the command into a variable, then execute it.

Then you can create mapping to "repeat" last menu cmd by reading the variable and execute.

When you create menu items, you do something like:

```
:menu File.SaveAndExit :call ExecMenuCmd('wq')
```

If you like, you could maintain a stack to store the commands triggered by menu, to implement more features.

Comment: Hi Kent, Tnx for replying. This would mean that I have to change all commands I created, isn't it? In above example the command would be `:call ExecMenuCmd(':call <SID>Test("%")<CR>')` isn't it? And in this function I execute `:call <SID>Test("%")<CR>` is that correct?  Btw Is it not possible to capture also the command in the invoked function (Test()) and put it in a variable?

Comment: you can exec a `:call F("arg")` like `exec 'call F("arg")'`. yes you need change the menu creation lines, if the feature is important enough for you. @Remonn

Comment: I updated my question, is that what you mean? btw.. I had one more problem.. What would be the subexe() argument if my function call is `:<C-U>call <SID>MyLoop("'<,'>", 'noloop')<CR>:set hls<CR>` (see double exec command and quotes within the exec)?

Comment: @Remonn the basic Idea is like that. but you need do some more work. if the command is so complicated as your example, you have to "parse" them. or , make a wrapper function.  again, if the "repeat" feature is so important to you, all those efforts are worthy.

Comment: Can you please give me just a little more info how to parse/wrap? btw.. I found a solution for the quotes adding an extra quote: `<SID>MyLoop("''<,''>", ''noloop'')` :) And last question, I don't know what you mean with maintain a stack to store.

Comment: @Remonn you can make a list, to push every command in. when you want to repeat, pop it out. it give you the possibility to track the command history. but it is further than your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Happy to be enable to repeat commands :)

Comment: Kent, do you know why this wrap doesn't work in our wrap function? `call SubExe("/text")` but this does work `exe '/text'`?

Comment: Kent, can I please ask you just one more thing? Hope you don't mind. I can't make this work in our function: `call SubExe(':normal \<C-W>T')<CR>` Why?

Comment: @Remonn what I can think of, when you define your menu command, better not define `normal` things. E.g. your example could be done by `wincmd` Again, the function is a work round. You have to check different situations to do corresponding handling.

Comment: Wow.. you seem to know everything :) Never heard of wincmd. Wincmd seems to work only with single commands, p.e. `wincmd w`, not `wincmd wt` or `wincmd w t`

Comment: Kent, with wincmd it doesn't seems to work. So it is not possible to pass call SubExe(':normal \<C-W>T')<CR> with our function? I'll stop trying :)

Comment: @Remonn I don't know what do you want, if you want to do `<C-W>T` you could do with wincmd and your function: `execute 'wincmd T'`  this does `Move the current window to a new tab page. `

Comment: Ah :) wincmd = '<C-W>'. I thought '<C-W>' is 'wincmd w' :) Now only '<C-R>' and '<ESC>' cannot be parsed :)

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? I hope you don't mind. I would like to copy the whole line of the SubExe Call and pass it to SubExe(), (or just the linenumber of current line) this to extract the description of current command. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Remonn I didn't get what do you want. recursion?  It seems that it is another question.

Comment: I want to parse the menu description with `call SubExe()` to the function! SubExe(argument,description). I need to know how to pass the linenumber of from where the subexe call is invoked. Yes it is a new question, I already asked it, but only you seems to know this kind of answers :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462500/how-to-know-from-which-line-a-script-is-called

Answer (score 0):

You could make a mapping in your .vimrc for entering the command mode, and then running the last command. Something like:

```
noremap <F8> :<Up><Cr>
```

That will repeat the last thing you ran from command mode whenever you press F8 in normal mode. You can change F8 to whatever you want.

Comment: `@:` will do the same , without any mapping

Comment: @mb14, thank you. I regret that it still doesn't work with menu commands calling a function.