# How to know from which line a script is called?

Tags: function, vim, line, exe, line-numbers

I would like to know from which line a script is called.

Code:

```
...
line 500
line 501  an <silent> 98.80.00 &Files.Test\ single\     :call Func('%')<CR>
line 502
etc
```

desired output: `501`

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you calling this script from your .vimrc? Or some other file?

Comment: @Zach, from the gvim menu :)

Comment: Kent, Thanks for replying. When I do this, it returns the linenumber of the mouse in current file which I'm in (not the linenumber in menu.vim). BTW...What I want to do is to pass the description (in this case `Test Single` with `call Func` to the function Func()). My idea is to pass the linenumber, read the line in the external file menu.vim and extract the description of this line (`Test Single`). So on for every line.

Comment: @Remonn I'm deleting my answer as I have no idea how to do what you want.

Comment: @Remonn I removed my comment since I realized that I didn't understand your question when I posted it. Now I felt I know your intention. so I added an answer. If I thought in a wrong way again, I am gonna remove that answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the question about "do you really need this?", here is a trick:

```
"foo
"bar
let a = 5
let a = 5
let a = 5
call  Foo(search('very special string'))
let a = 5
let a = 5
fun! Foo(callerLineNumber)
    echo a:callerLineNumber
endf
```

this will print the line number of line `call  Foo(search('"very special string"'))`

well you have to make a "really special string" in search pattern.

Comment: Kent, nice, but not easy to do because I have to fill in a different search string in every function call. Is there no way to copy the whole line to `fun! Foo(callerLineNumber)`?

Comment: btw, I can't make it work when menu.vim isn't open and in my case I call Foo(search('very special string')) from within the GUI or from the commandline. Menu.vim is not open.

Comment: @Remonn noway in function to know the caller position, you have to somehow pass it in. I don't know what exactly you want to do, but this trick does let you pass the location (line#) of caller to the function. It answers the question, IMO.  If it didn't solve your real problem, you made it into a X-Y problem.

Comment: Kent, I need the descriptions to create a lastcommands menu. I want to use descriptions in order to avoid putting commands in this menu. Maybe I did something wrong but in my test it did not pass the linenumber if I'm not with my mouse in menu.vim.

Comment: Is this possible? `for line in readfile('c:\progra~2\vim\vim74\menu.vim') | if line =~ 'very special string' | echo line | endif | endfor` Better to make a copy of menu.vim first or is it no problem to read in the file?

Comment: Well no matter. You're right, you answered my question. Unfortunately it is not a solution because I forgot to write in my question that I want to know the line number of caller to the function with or without being in menu.vim. Search() does a search in the document where I'm currently in. It echos "very special string" not found.

Comment: I could delete the answer if it didn't solve your problem. or misled you to a new problem. Sorry. @Remonn